# Numpy arrays share memory even though all tests are false???? Is this a bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, memory, shared-memory

I have some code, and I cannot **for the life of me figure out how these are sharing memory!!!!** All tests are false (as shown), and yet, the memory locations seems to be the same, functionally, and visually. I have **spent hours trying to troubleshoot** and cannot figure it out.  **PLEASE HELP!!! WHY ARE THESE ARRAYS SHARING MEMORY!??**

*listOfValues* and *listOfxValues* are sharing memory when they shouldn't be.

WARNING: ugly, ugly code, I apologize, its been a rough day.

```
listOfLists = []
splitold=0

#split arrays into each bin
for split in splitInd:
    splitnew=split
    listOfLists.append(xind[splitold:splitnew])
    splitold=split

listOfValues = np.array(listOfLists.copy())
#convert to float type
for i,lst in enumerate(listOfValues):
    listOfValues[i] = lst.astype(float)

listOfxValues = np.copy(listOfValues)

#PRINT TROUBLESHOOTING
print(listOfxValues.data)
print(listOfValues.data)
print(listOfValues is listOfxValues)
print(listOfValues == listOfxValues)
print(listOfValues.data is listOfxValues.data)
print(listOfValues.data == listOfxValues.data)
print(np.shares_memory(listOfxValues,listOfValues))
print(listOfxValues.__array_interface__['data'][0] == listOfValues.__array_interface__['data'][0]) 
print(listOfxValues.__array_interface__['data'][0] == listOfValues.__array_interface__['data'][0])

#exchange indexed values for real values
for each in range(len(listOfValues)):
    for i,index in enumerate(listOfLists[each]):
        listOfxValues[each][i] = xdata[index]
        listOfValues[each][i] = ydata[index]

maxArrayInd = []
#get max indices
for array in listOfValues:
    maxArrayInd.append(np.argmax(array))

maxX = []
maxY = []
#get values for max indices
for idx,mx in enumerate(maxArrayInd):
    maxX.append(listOfxValues[idx][mx])
    maxY.append(listOfValues[idx][mx])
```

This code outputs:

```
<memory at 0x00000215644C5640>
<memory at 0x00000215644C5640>
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

The memory location is clearly the same, despite all tests coming out false. Its breaking my code.
Please help!!

And thank you, pardon the desperation.

EDIT:

I wasn't able to figure out why its behaving this way, but moving

```
listOfxValues = np.copy(listOfValues)
```

above #convert to float type fixed the error. I still can't figure out why they were sharing memory, and why this fixed it. I understand the difference between pointers, views, copies, etc (at least a basic understanding), but this still doesn't make sense why I had the problem.

Thanks for all your answers! I learned some at least!

Comment: See the dox on `numpy.copy`.  Note that it produces a *shallow* copy.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html

Comment: Btw. `ndarray.ctypes.data` should behave more within your expectation. But if all you you want is to check for shared memory then use `shares_memory`.

Comment: I usually find `__array_interface__['data'][0]` to be a reliable shared memory test; though I usually display it, rather than use a `==` test.  But if you want a good answer, gives us code that we can run and do our own tests.  Looks like you need at the very least you need to provide an example of  `splitInd`.  What's the `dtype`?  I wonder if it is `object`?

Comment: @Air, `copy` is enough if the dtype is numeric.  But I suspect he has object dtype arrays.

Comment: Why do you use `listOfValues[each][i]` instead of the preferred multidimensional indexing `listOfValues[each, i]`?

Answer (score 6):

The `.data` attribute is a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) object. *A new `memoryview` is created each time you access the attribute.*  The address shown when you print the `memoryview` is the address of the Python object, not of the underlying data in the array.

When Python executes `print(listOfxValues.data)`, accessing the `.data` attributes triggers NumPy code that creates a new `memoryview`, and that object is passed to `print()`.  After the call to `print()` completes, there are no longer any Python objects holding references to the `memoryview`, so it can be freed by the garbage collector.  Then, when you call `print(listOfValues.data)`, a new `memoryview` object is created, but it turns out that Python happens to reuse the same memory that had been used in the previous call.

If you do this:

```
a = listOfxValues.data
b = listOfValues.data
print(a)
print(b)
```

the memory addresses of the two `memoryview`s will always be different.
That is also true if `a` and `b` are created by accessing the `.data` attribute of the *same array*, e.g.

```
In [23]: x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [24]: a = x.data

In [25]: b = x.data

In [26]: a
Out[26]: <memory at 0x120975050>

In [27]: b
Out[27]: <memory at 0x120808c80>
```

Comment: This discussion on Views vs Copies in NumPy might be helpful:  https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html (and @Warren Weckesser is one of the authors).

Comment: So why does a `memoryview` object get labelled as `memory`?  That's terribly misleading.  Thanks Python.

Answer (score 0):

Object dtype is the best explanation for your observed behavior.  I'll illustrate.

If I make an object dtype array (v. 1.19 now wants the explicit object dtype):

```
In [55]: x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4,5]], object)                                                       
In [56]: x                                                                                           
Out[56]: array([list([1, 2]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

and a copy:

```
In [57]: xc = x.copy()
```

The 'data' buffer location is different:

```
In [58]: x.__array_interface__['data'][0]                                                            
Out[58]: 35624384
In [59]: xc.__array_interface__['data'][0]                                                           
Out[59]: 40985936
```

But the first element of the copy is the same as the original:

```
In [60]: id(x[0])                                                                                    
Out[60]: 139816762070344
In [61]: id(xc[0])                                                                                   
Out[61]: 139816762070344
```

That is, it's the same `list` object.  Modifying one modifies the other:

```
In [62]: x[0][1] = 10         # can't use x[0, 1] = 10 syntax                                                                         
In [63]: x                                                                                           
Out[63]: array([list([1, 10]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
In [64]: xc                                                                                          
Out[64]: array([list([1, 10]), list([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

`x.copy()` is fine when `x` is a numeric dtype, but not with object dtype.  As with a list, it requires a `deepcopy` if you want them to be independent.  Don't use object dtype arrays naively, even when it's easy to create them!